# Port Scanning - States definition

Tags: network-scanners

I am currently reading the "NMAP Network Scanning" book by Gordon Fyodor Lyon. On page 77 there is a description on how NMAP categorizes the ports based on host's responses (or not).

What would help me to better understand them is a clear association to the flags returned by the host. Therefore I created the list below and would appreciate to have it doubled checked by you guys:

```
 State             Response

 Open              SYN/ACK (SYN probe)
 Closed            RST (SYN probe)
 Filtered          No Answer or ICMP Type 3 and 13 (SYN probe)
 Unfiltered        No Answer or ICMP Type 3 and 13 (ACK probe)
 Open/Filtered     No Answer (UDP, FIN, NULL, XMAS probes)
 Closed/Filtered   No Answer or RST (Idle Scan)
```

Comment: You can not getter better clarification than on the official [documentation](http://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html)

Comment: @begueradj I agree, however the documentation does not explicitly mention it...

Comment: I have a copy of this book too. Can you clarify your question a bit? I'd like to help you out but I'm not sure exactly what type of answer you're looking for. "*What would help me to better understand them is* ***a clear association to the flags returned by the host.***" The way I understand your question; that `State & Response` table is the best answer. So what more would you like to know?

Answer (score 8):

1. Open:

   - The attacker sends a SYN probe to the port he wants to test
   - The port sends back a packet with SYN and ACK flags
2. Closed:

   - The attacker sends a SYN probe to the port he wants to test
   - The port sends back RST/ACK packet directly
3. Filtered:

   - The attacker sends a SYN probe to the port he wants to test
   - Two scenarios:

     - The port responds back with ICMP error messages such as type 3 code 13 (destination unreachable: communication administratively prohibited)
     - More frustrating scenario for the attacker: the SYN probe is dropped (no answer at all)
4. Unfiltered:

   - The attacker sends a ACK probe to the port he wants to test
   - The port responds with RST packet
5. Open/Filtered:

   - The attacker sends a UDP, IP, FIN, NULL or Xmas probes to the port he wants to test
   - No answer is received
6. Closed/Filtered:

   - The attacker performs an idle scan  (`-sI`)
   - The ***zombie*** machine receives RST packet,  or nothing at all from the **target** machine (this means the attacker will receive `IPID=1` from the zombie)

Comment: Unfiltered: "Only the ACK scan, which is used to map firewall rulesets, classifies ports into this state": https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html

Comment: @Michael Yes, you are right: it was just a typo as I copy/past the phrase: *The attacker sends a SYN probe to the port he wants to test*.  I had to rectify it right away after the copy/past but I forgot .Than you for paying attention