# Some questions about port-scans

Tags: firewalls, enumeration

I have two questions and it seems like this website is the perfect place to ask them.

1. I read a post earlier concerning port scans and one of the answers stated something along the lines of: *"There is no definitive protocol that can determine if a host is alive"*, is this actually true? Surely there must be a way?
2. This got me thinking; how does port-scanning on a computer outside of your network actually work? Is it even possible just by knowing their public IP?

Comment: Welcome. May be the [**answer here**](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95255/port-scanning-states-definition) will be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I read a post earlier concerning port scans and one of the answer stated something along the lines of:"There is no definitive protocol that can determine if a host is alive", is this actually true? Surely there must be a way?

No, and this is a good thing. If I host a server, surely it's my choice who I send data to? I could filter out entire continents if I only want to be able to access my server from, say, The Netherlands if that's the only place I access it from. Unless you happen to scan from the Netherlands, you wouldn't know whether my server is up.

Now that's a server, but what about your laptop? Why should anyone be able to learn whether your laptop is turned on just by knowing its IPv4 or IPv6 address? Most NAT routers and stateful firewalls don't return anything (not even an ICMP Host Unreachable or TCP RST packet) when you try to reach a computer in its network -- and I think that's good design.

If you're in the same LAN, I think there are typically ways to figure it out using arping (ARP ping), but technically you could prevent that from working too if you want to. I just doubt anyone bothers.

> 2.This got me thinking; how does port-scanning on a computer outside of your network actually work? Is it even possible just by knowing their public IP?

Oh, I think I half answered this already... I'll dive into this a little deeper.

Port scanning scans ports, but you seem to be asking about checking whether a host is up in the first place.

Usually people access the internet via their router (or modem or something). Strictly speaking a router just routes, but what consumers call a router is a device that does all sorts of stuff (DHCP, DNS, NAT, etc.). Most people only have one IPv4 address due to the shortage and everyone in the local network gets a local address (typically 192.168.x.x). The router performs a function called NAT, which translates between the local address and the public address.

When you connect to some IP address on the Internet, your system sends a SYN packet there and a connection is setup. Your router gets that, and any responses will be forwarded to your computer (based on the port the packet is addressed to). Any SYN packets or UDP packets or something will bounce off because the router wouldn't know which internal host to deliver it to. If you setup port forwarding, this tells the router to always forward certain ports to certain hosts.

If you have IPv6 or a public IPv4 address, the router's firewall will (or should) perform a similar function. It doesn't do address translation because it's not needed (everyone has their own address) but it does filter incoming connections that you didn't initiate. This is a security feature.

So scanning to see whether a certain computer is up won't work because the router just drops anything it doesn't recognize. It might also return ICMP packets saying the address is administratively prohibited (when the firewall is simply active), which doesn't tell you anything either.

Comment: Man, this is an excellent explanation. Thanks heaps. So you're saying that port-scans and host discovery is practically impossible unless the host's router is configured to respond?

Comment: @Inquisitive Since the default is to not respond (on most consumer routers), yes, that is usually the case. I'm glad you found the explanation useful!